Colimits of locally convex spaces in the categories of topological vector spaces vs locally convex spaces
Let $S$ be a set and let $V_s$ be a family of locally convex topological vector spaces (LCSs) indexed by $s \in S$. Let $V$ be a vector space (without topology) and let $T_s:V_s \to V$ be a family of linear maps such that the images of $T_s$ collectively span $V$. There exist topologies on $V$ making it into the colimit of the maps $T_s:V_s \to V$ in the categories $\mathsf{TVS}$ and $\mathsf{LCS}$ of topological vector spaces and locally convex vector spaces, resptively, and these topologies may not coincide (see: http://www-users.math.umn.edu/~garrett/m/fun/uncountable_coproducts.pdf). We write $\mathrm{colim}_{TVS} V_s$ and $\mathrm{colim}_{LCS} V_s$ for the respective colimits (both with underlying vector space $V$).
I am interested in what properties $\mathrm{colim}_{TVS} V_s$ and $\mathrm{colim}_{LCS} V_s$ necessarily share. In particular,
$\textbf{Question:}$ If $\mathrm{colim}_{TVS} V_s$ is Hausdorff does it follow that $\mathrm{colim}_{LCS} V_s$ is necessarily Hausdorff as well? What if we assume $S$ is countable? (The converse is clear)
Since colimits can be built out of coproducts and quotients, and quotients of LCSs taken in $\mathsf{TVS}$ and $\mathsf{LCS}$ coincide, we may ignore the maps $T_s$ and rephrase the question in the following way. Write $\bigoplus^{TVS} V_s$ and $\bigoplus^{LCS} V_s$ for the coproducts of the $V_s$ in $\mathsf{TVS}$ and $\mathsf{LCS}$ respectively, both of which have the direct sum $\bigoplus V_s$ as underlying vector space.
$\textbf{Equivalent question:}$ Is every closed subspace of $\bigoplus^{TVS} V_s$ also closed in $\bigoplus^{LCS} V_s$? What if $S$ is countable?
Edit: The statement is true in the case when $S$ is countable by the comment of Jochen Wengenroth.

Countable colimits of locally convex spaces in the categories TVS and LCS coincide. This is proposition 8.1.8 in the book Barrelled Locally Convex Spaces of Bonet and Perez Carreras (it should also be in Köthe's Topological Vector Spaces).

@JochenWengenroth Thank you!

Another reference is Topological Vector Spaces -- the theory without convexity conditions by Adasch, Ernst, and Keim, proposition (6) on page 22. The book is available here:
https://link.springer.com/book/10.1007/BFb0068514
However, I did not find there the answer to your question in the uncountable case.
